# Is there a way to store 64, 128 or 256 byte values in 32 bit Excel's VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

The 32 bit Excel supports long data type but the 64 bit Excel can support long long type which is 64 bits. Is there a way to create a user defined function in 32-bit Excel VBA that takes 64, 128 or even 256 bits? If I was using C I would create a struct and use a pointer to it. But don't know what to do with VBA.

Comment: One route would be to create a COM object to model that. You'll probably find a library out there which already has that. Writing it back to the workbook would be a challenge. You could use a string at that point?

Comment: COM object? That sounds complicated.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA you can use Byte arrays to model arbitrarily long sets of bits.

Comment: Could you kindly specify an example please

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/12121/assignment-to-and-from-a-byte-array

Answer (score 1):

Looking for [Type statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement)?

```vb
Type LongLongX86
    Upper as Long
    Lower as Long
End Type
```